# Custom site administration form/page

Tags: forms

I'm looking to create a page on my site that will allow certain users to perform administrative tasks without them needing to have access to the entire administrative back end.

I want to create a page/form that will allow my user to:

- Change the default logo (like is on the Appearance page)
- Change the site slogan
- Put the site into maintenance mode/Change the maintenance mode
  text

I have no doubt there is not a module out there with this capability, so I assume I am going to have to make use of the form API, but I was wondering if anyone could give me a point in the right direction.

Kind regards

Comment: Sure.  All of the forms you want are defined within the system module's system.admin.inc file, so, just pull out the pieces you want from each, put them in your own form, and then have that called from a menu item that has permissions that you have granted to your mini-admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @jimajamma said in the question comments, you most likely want to create a custom module that implements `hook_menu()`, creates a form, and handles the form submission. Also, notice the trick where you can use the `drupal_get_form()` page callback to build a page that is just rendering a form. To use this, you need to pass the name of the function that returns your form as a page argument.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function demo_menu() {
  $items['admin/config/demo'] = array(
    'title' => 'Demo page title',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('demo_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer content'),    
    // Choose an appropriate permission or create your own using hook_permission()!
  );
}

/**
 * Provides an admin form to change the site slogan, put the site into
 * maintenance mode.
 */
function demo_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // Adapted from system.admin.inc line 1495.
  $form['site_slogan'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Slogan'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('site_slogan', ''),
    '#description' => t("Change the site's slogan."),
  );

  // Taken from system.admin.inc line 2201.
  $form['maintenance_mode'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Put site into maintenance mode'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('maintenance_mode', 0),
    '#description' => t('When enabled, only users with the "Use the site in maintenance mode" <a href="@permissions-url">permission</a> are able to access your site to perform maintenance; all other visitors see the maintenance mode message configured below. Authorized users can log in directly via the <a href="@user-login">user login</a> page.', array('@permissions-url' => url('admin/people/permissions'), '@user-login' => url('user'))),
  );
  $form['maintenance_mode_message'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Maintenance mode message'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('maintenance_mode_message', t('@site is currently under maintenance. We should be back shortly. Thank you for your patience.', array('@site' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')))),
    '#description' => t('Message to show visitors when the site is in maintenance mode.')
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Submits demo_form().
 */
function demo_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  variable_set('site_slogan', $form_state['values']['site_slogan']);
  variable_set('maintenance_mode', $form_state['values']['maintenance_mode']);
  variable_set('maintenance_mode_message', $form_state['values']['maintenance_mode_message']);
}
```

The form elements for the logo are a bit more complicated, but I suggest you take a look at `system_theme_settings()` in system.admin.inc line 399.

Comment: Excellent, this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for, I can use this as a starting point and hopefully I can work from here to get what I wanted, Thanks :)